# How can I resolve $http.get promise in service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need resolve the http call in my service to return the data, not a promise.

Is this possible with AngularJS (with Ionic Framework)?

**Service code:**

```
.factory('ClientService', function ($http) {

    const url = 'http://myAPIurl';

    var self = this;
    var result = [];

    self.getClients = function () {
        return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }    

    return self;
})
```

In my controller, I use this code that actually returns a promise of my request. In this point, the *$scope.clients* must be filled with data.

**Controller code:**

```
ClientService.getClients().then(function (response) {
    $scope.clients = response;
}, function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Your code already does what you want it to. There's no way other than not using ajax at all to make $scope.clients get populated any faster.

Comment: The only optimization i can see from that and it will be an micro-micro-micro optimization is sack off the `.then()` in your service. so `return  $http.get(url);` and in your controller access the object in its entity. `ClientService.getClients().then(function (response) {
    $scope.clients = response.data;
});` @PankajParkar as it stands the `data` property is already retrieved in the initial `.then()` in the service.

Comment: @ste2425 Oh that my bad read..Sorry about that

Comment: thanks for reply! I will retry the implementation in my application context and come back to post results.

Comment: I got it! I had inserted some code after ClientService.getClients() call, that wasn´t executed in sequence (after resolve the http request). Now, I transfered this code inside ClientService.getClients(). Thanks a lot! And sorry my poor english